# How to get all values of input once in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Here is my form and I tried to take all the values from the form when submit button is clicked

```
  <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post"  id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>User Form</legend>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i></span>
  <input  name="name" placeholder="Enter User Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Age</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i></span>
  <input  name="age" placeholder="Enter Age " class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button name="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then I write the script to take all values when submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var name = $("#name").val();  
        var age= $("#age").val();  

        console.log(name);
        console.log(age);

    });
});
</script>
```

But it is logging the values when submitting.Any help is appreciated

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Do you want to capture all the values without actually submitting the form?

Comment: No I want to capture the values and send it when submitted

Comment: As you mention, and is apparent from the code, you are already getting all the values when the form is submitted. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: I am not getting the values which means it does not log anything in the console when I log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
```

You are assigin  a click event handler to an element with id `submit`. There is no such element in you code.

What you could rather do is assign a handler to the form's [submit event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/). Also, there are no elements with id `name` and `age`. You can use the query selector with the input's name attribute.

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function(e) {
  var name = $('#contact_form input[name="name"]').val();
  var age = $('#contact_form input[name="age"]').val();

  console.log(name);
  console.log(age);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the form input values by using `$('#formId').serialize()` function. But as per your code:

```
<button name="submitbutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
```

you are using a `button` of type submit, which submits the form and you did not get any value in your ajax code. So change it it:

```
<button name="submitbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-success" >Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
```

and try again. To get the individual value you can use

`var name = $("#name").val();`

with the above mentioned change.